# Null Reference exception in android studio while connecting to VSTS git

Tags: azure-devops, git-credential-manager

I am using android studio and VSTS (git). out of nowhere i faced an error

> fatal: NullReferenceException encountered.
>      Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

event though i am signed in VSTS it keep asking to sign in again and again in android studio. 
I tried to clone project and the same happens. 
Even i reinstalled my android studio from start
Git is also installed on my computer, and passes the test in android studio but still cant go through to my repository.

This started when i tried to push my project in the repository and gave me this error. Searched the whole internet almost but cant find any thing like this.
Anyone share your expertise regarding git(VSTS)

[image: Image of trying to clone from repository]

Comment: [This](https://dzone.com/articles/nullreferenceexception-in-windows-with-git-fetch-o)

Comment: Thank you so much @kostix  This was very helpful